# Establecer el máximo numero de caracteres en un TEdit en Inno Setup?

Tags: inno-setup, pascalscript

Tengo un TEdit en Inno Setup y quisiera establecer un máximo de 20 caracteres:

```
eDBnameT := TNewEdit.Create(TerminalPage);
  eDBnameT.Top := ScaleY(270);
  eDBnameT.Left := ScaleX(130);
  eDBnameT.Width := ScaleX(200);
  eDBnameT.Height := ScaleY(23);
  eDBnameT.Text := 'sicar';
  eDBnameT.Parent := WizardForm.InnerPage;
  eDBnameT.Visible := False;
```

He intentado con:

```
eDBnameT.Length := 20;
```

pero me tira error.

Comment: Length no es una propiedad de TNewEdit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La propiedad se llama `MaxLength`, la manera de establecer el maximo es pasar el entero al igual que pasas los valores a las otras propiedades:

```
eDBnameT.MaxLength := 20;
```